# mercurial automated deployment on staging and production server using bitbucket

Tags: php, mercurial, tortoisehg, bitbucket

Presently we are using mercurial with tortoise HG for GUI to manage Repositories and our repositories are created on bitbucket.

Now I want to deploy my source code to my (staging/test) and production server. I had also googled for the same but I didn't found any good answer.

I also like to manage my sql database with mercurial. is it possible to make our database versions ?

Please help me!!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You cannot store your database in a repository but you can export your Database.
You can export your database either with the command line (`mysqldump`) or with a MySQL database manager. But I would recommend writing a command line script which does it for you automatically (because it is annoying to write that command several times).

[Here](http://ben.kulbertis.org/2011/10/synchronizing-a-mysql-database-with-git-and-git-hooks/) is an article about synchronising a mysql database with git (which contains automatic scripts) that should help you. It shouldn't be hard to rewrite these scripts for HG.

When you push code, it is only pushed to the bitbucket server. If you want that your servers (or developers, tests or whatever) get the code you will need to pull the code from server (doing it with the command line command `hg pull` or in your GUI with the "Pull" button - google should help you to find it). There is no way that your server does it automatically because it would offer an security issues. (What would happen if somebody gain access to a developer account and if he push some code, which does bad things like pushing your customer's datas to another server? And to the "database" part. You should only save the structure in your repo, not user datas, etc).

Well, you should apply your code on your (test) server only with the command line (or a FTP client or whatever) because: The script, which runs, needs property a restart, or if you use a PHP server, your database may need an update when a new tables has been added).

Comment: "I want to deploy my source code to my (staging/test) and production server" this means...

i have 2 servers 1st for testing for testers and developers 2nd is live, 

i want to push my code from bitbucket or mercurial to my test as well as live server.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about versioning of **database evolution**, not about data in database, you have to read about [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/quickstart) and using [database changelog file](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/databasechangelog) for publishing DB-changes.

Short intro:

- Each change in schema (creating database is also mandatory zero-level change) stored by Liqubase as changelog
- Changelog stored with changeset, which introduced this change (added to set of previous changelogs)
- Updating project from state A to state B assumes applying all changesets in A::B range to code and all database changelogs in these changesets